# Trying to open a text file and create a list of lines separating the between sentences.

Tags: python, text, ascii

Using Python 3.6 and Spyder. This one is driving me crazy and should be easy, but I am stumped. I am trying to open a text file and create a list of the lines. I am trying to separate the lines based on periods. I want to be able to do something like list_of_lines[25]. I keep getting the following error AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'decode'. I tried to open the file normally and then use .split(), but kept getting ascii errors.

Any suggestions or pointing me in the right direction would be great.

```
with open("SORROWS_OF_YOUNG_WERTHER.txt") as book:
    text_file = book.decode('ascii')
    list_of_lines = [word.split('.') for word in text_file.readlines()]
    print(list_of_lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are opening with the binary flag `'b'`. The file is already text, so there is no need to decode.

This should work fine:

```
with open("SORROWS_OF_YOUNG_WERTHER.txt") as book:
    list_of_lines = [line.decode('utf-8').split('.') for line in book.readlines()]
    print(list_of_lines)
```

Be aware that the output is however going to split each line at each period.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought as well. When I tried to use the split() method with the non-decoded file I got an error for unrecognized characters.

Comment: Are you sure your input is ascii then? It could be another encoding.

Comment: This is the error. UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1236: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I tried ascii and UTF-8. I would prefer the latter.

Comment: No, I saved the text file in sublime with UTF-8 encoding. It threw the error above. Tried it without encoding and it did the same thing. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I just updated my answer above to include the decoding. Try that now.

Notice that you have to decode each line, not the file handle like you were doing in your initial question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156608/discussion-between-stuart-buckingham-and-eric).

Comment: @Eric: can you post some lines from your input file